# Creating Percentages instead of Sums using melt/cast

Tags: r

Simple example.  I would like to create a data frame of percentages using cast/melt instead of sums.

Example.

```
eg <- data.frame(
Time = factor(c(1,2,1,2)), 
A1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), 
A2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
B1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0)
)

eg.m <- melt(eg,id="Time")
eg.c <- cast(eg.m,Time ~ variable, sum, margins="grand_row")
```

In the above example, I can produce the sum and total.  Rather than produce the sum, is there a means to produce the percentage in each cell, i.e. sum of cell / gran_row?  I know I can do some stuff here using ddply and reshape, but wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
  Time  A1  A2  B1
1    1 0.5 0.5   0
2    2 1.0 1.0   0
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want the final data.frame to look like?

Comment: I would like it to be the cumsum of the values in the column divided by the total.  So rather than sums, cumsum/total. So using the above data, we have .5,1 for column 2 or A1, .5,1 for column 3 or A2, 0,0 for column 4 or B1

Comment: @davewolfs Instead of explaining it in the comments it probably would have been more efficient to actually add the example data frame at the end of the question like gsk3 requested.

Comment: Added what I believe to be your desired output.

Comment: @gsk3 Works great, just need to great rid of `NaN

Comment: Well you need to reformulate the question then since 0/0=NaN ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems hard to me to avoid doing this in two steps.  The problem is that you want to run the cumsum/sum function on the output of the dcast operation, unless I'm misunderstanding what you want still.

First is as you have it:

```
eg.c <- dcast(eg.m,Time ~ variable, sum )
```

Second is just applying the cumsum/sum function to the columns:

```
japply(eg.c, sapply(eg.c, is.numeric ), function(x) cumsum(x)/sum(x) )

  Time  A1  A2  B1
1    1 0.5 0.5 NaN
2    2 1.0 1.0 NaN
```

Where `japply` is a function I have in my .RProfile:

```
# Takes a data.frame and returns a data.frame with only the specified columns transformed
japply <- function(df, sel, FUN=function(x) x, ...) {
  df[,sel] <- sapply( df[,sel], FUN, ... )
  df
}
```